# bucle para generar variables iteradas condicionadas por fechas

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo un dataframe en donde tengo una variable fecha de nacimiento en el formato yyyy-mm-dd que incluyen desde el mes de enero-19 hasta septiembre-19.

Requiere es generar 9 variables dicotómicas, que tomen valor=1  si cumplen una condición de un cohorte de fecha

Entonces cada dicotómica ( den_2019_`i' ) se define., si la fecha de nacimiento está comprendida desde el primer día del mes hasta el primer día del mes siguiente.

Por ejemplo si una observación tiene como fecha_nacimiento = 15-01-2019,está comprendido entre [01-01-2019; 01-02-2019> ,su  den_2019_1=1.

Intenté una forma pero no funcionó y no me queda claro, lo comparto para referencia:

```
formato_fecha = "%Y-%m-%d"
list_mes_actual=['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09']
list_mes_siguiente=['02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09','10']

    for i in list_mes_actual:
        for j in list_mes_siguiente:
            cnv_csv['den_2019'_i] = ((cnv_renaes['fe_nacido'] >= datetime.strptime('2019-i-1', formato_fecha)) & (cnv_renaes['fe_nacido'] < datetime.strptime('2019-j-1', formato_fecha)))
```

Agradezco su respuestas.

Comment: Disculpa mi torpeza Kevin, pero no consigo entender tu pregunta. Ponme ejemplos de valores cuando una fecha debería de ser 0, y cuando debería ser 1